# Update a Drop-Down Menu when a cell value changes (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Problem with a Drop-Down menu. The Drop-Down menu (B5) has a range of four values (`J1:J4`) that are dependent on a value in a cell above the Drop-Down menu (B3). When B3 is below a certain value, then the values in the range turn to `FALSE` (That part is on purpose and done with an easy if-function) and this is displayed in the Drop-Down menu, meaning you can chose the value `FALSE`. But when you first choose a value in the Drop-Down menu and later change the value in B3, say, reduce the value so the range-value should turn to `FALSE`, the value displayed in the Drop-Down menu does not update, while the value in the range changes just fine.

Is there a way to "force"-update the Drop-Down menu, each time the value in B3 changes?

Comment: Try repopulating the validation list on a `worksheet_change` event, but make sure you specify this event for `B3` using `Intersect`

Comment: @TimStack don't necessarily need to use the `Intersect` method. An easier option, based on the OPs understanding of VBA, could simply be `If Target.Address = $B$3` etc.

Comment: That's correct @Dean

Comment: I tried it on My Worksheet. It Automatically updates the Drop Down List when you change the value in the Reference cell in your case `B3`. But Yeah It does not change the already selected value from the Drop down. Which can be handled by `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: @Mikku What command do I have to use on B5? I tried with .run but that doesn't seem to work:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
 
 
If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
 
Range("B5").Run
 
End If
 
 
 
End Sub

Comment: Not Run. Maybe Just clear it's contents so that you can choose a fresh value from the updated list. Try `Range("B5").ClearContents`

Comment: @Mikku Perfect, that works, thank you very much :D

Comment: @LaurinAllemand ... I have added an answer for Users. Accept it as answer so anyone looking can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add an Worksheet Event to capture the Change in Cell `B3` and clear it's value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then 
 Range("B5").ClearContents 
 End If 

End Sub
```